# Compilation error when using C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

Could anyone explain why am I not able to use C++ templates like this:

```
template <typename T> class A {
public:
    typedef std::vector<T>::iterator myiterator;

    A(T value)
        :   v(10, value)
    {
    }

    myiterator begin()
    {
        return v.begin();
    }

    myiterator end()
    {
        return v.end();
    }

public:
    std::vector<T> v;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a(10);

    for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I got the compilation error on the line where myiterator alias is declared; the error is: "missing ';' before identifier 'myiterator'".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
typedef std::vector<T>::iterator myiterator;
```

to

```
typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator myiterator;
```

Since you are accessing a type through a templated type (vector) you need to help the compiler to disambiguate. `vector<T>::iterator` could be either a static member, or a type. Without more knowledge of T the compiler cannot be sure. Using the `typename` keyword there tells the compiler "treat this as a type."

For more details, see [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Yeah, this works! But why the 'typedef' is not enough here? Why should I specify the extra typename keyword?

Comment: C++ is a complex monster, that's why ;) Any time you want to access a type that is dependent on a template parameter, you need `typename`.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler should know `std::vector` is a type, it's dependent scope:

```
typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator myiterator;
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the helpful error message:

```
 'std::vector<T>::iterator' : dependent name is not a type
          prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
```

You need to tell it you are declaring a type:

```
typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator myiterator;
//      ^^^^^^^^
```